# Duda con manipulación de una vista desde una clase externa

Tags: android, android-studio, gridview

Necesito ayuda porque estoy bloqueado, estaba realizando un buscaminas hice toda la lógica en un clase esta clase básicamente tiene dos matrices una que indica que objeto hay en la casilla si es pista mina o banderita de marca y la otra la visibilidad. Hasta hay todo va bien.

En android studio tenemos el mainactivity que crea la partida y luego crea un gridlayout. Ese grid layout se configura y crea tantos botones como casillas pero estos botones son un botón personalizado.

Aquí pongo la funcion que hay en el mainactivity crear tablero:

```
    public void creartablero(int tamagno){
    grid = findViewById(R.id.tablero);
    grid.setRowCount(tamagno);
    grid.setColumnCount(tamagno);
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();       //Variable para guardar el tamagno de la pantalla
    display.getSize(size);          //Obtengo el tamagno
    int width = size.x/tamagno;
    int heigth = size.y/(tamagno+2);//Para salva el menu
    int contadorPosicion =0;
    for(int x=0; x < tamagno ; x++){
        for(int y=0; y < tamagno ; y++){
            contadorPosicion++;
            BotonJuego botonCasilla = new BotonJuego(this, width,heigth,x,y,contadorPosicion,partida.getPulsadas(x,y));
            grid.addView(botonCasilla);
        }
    }
}
```

Aquí pongo la clase que define el boton personalizado botonCasilla:

```
public class BotonJuego extends AppCompatButton implements View.OnClickListener ,View.OnLongClickListener{
private static int width;
private static int height;
private int position;
private int x;
private int y;
private Context context;
private boolean desvelado;  //

public BotonJuego(Context context, int width, int heigth, int x, int y, int position,boolean desvelado){
    super(context);
    this.width = width;
    this.height = heigth;
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
    this.position=position;
    this.context = context;
    this.desvelado = desvelado; //Indica si esta o no desvelado o no
    configurateBoton();
}

private void configurateBoton (){
    if (!this.desvelado) {
        setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.boton_casilla);
        setText(Integer.toString(this.position));
        setOnClickListener(this);
        setOnLongClickListener(this);
    }//Es un boton sin mostrar
    else{//El icono esta develado
        setClickable(false);
        int value = partida.getValuePosition(this.x,this.y);
        if (value >= 0) {//Es una pista o vacio
            setText(Integer.toString(value));
            setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.boton_casilla_pulsada);
        }
    }

    GridLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
    layoutParams.setMargins(0,0,0,0);
    layoutParams.width = this.width;
    layoutParams.height = this.height;
    setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    partida.setPulsadas(x,y);
    System.out.println("Has pulsado x:" + this.x + " y : " + this.y);
    //v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
}

@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    partida.addOrRemoveMarcaHipotenochas(x,y);
    //v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    return false;
}
```

}

Vale todo esto funciona. Pero ahora necesito cada vez que se pulse uno de los botones se refresque el grid con el nuevo estado del mapa.
Para ello había pensado hacer una función static llamada refrescar que elimine el grid y lo vuelva a crear, el problema es que no se como mandar la vista.
La clase que había pensado es la siguiente, esta clase la llamarían los botones cada vez que sean pulsado forzando a mostrar la nueva situación del mapa:

```
public class RefescoDisplay {

public BotonJuego botonCasilla;

public static void refrescartablero(Context c, View v){

    int tamagno = partida.getTamagnoMatriz();
    if (grid != null )  grid.removeAllViews();                      //Reiniciamo los botenes
    grid = v.findViewById(R.id.tablero);
    grid.setRowCount(tamagno);
    grid.setColumnCount(tamagno);
    Display display = ((Activity)c).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();       //Variable para guardar el tamagno de la pantalla
    display.getSize(size);          //Obtengo el tamagno
    int width = size.x/tamagno;
    int heigth = size.y/(tamagno+2);//Para salva el menu
    int contadorPosicion =0;
    for(int x=0; x < tamagno ; x++){
        for(int y=0; y < tamagno ; y++){
            contadorPosicion++;
            BotonJuego botonCasilla = new BotonJuego(c, width,heigth,x,y,contadorPosicion,partida.getPulsadas(x,y));
            grid.addView(botonCasilla);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Ahora el problema yo se capturar el contexto pero no capturar la vista para poder modificarla desde la clase RefescoDisplay y por mas que busco no encuentro nada.

Me podéis ayudar por favor. Muchas gracias de antemano

Al final modifique como lo iba hacer, he hecho que el propio botón se encarge de re dibujar a los otros botones.
Aun así para conseguir el contesto de cualquier parte del mainActivity hice el siguiente truco en el mainactivity:

```
    private static MainActivity myContext;

public MainActivity() {
    myContext =  this;
}

public static MainActivity getInstance() {
    return myContext;
}
```

Comment: hola me parece que seria mejor solucion usar un callback y que el Activity se encargue de tener el metodo para refrescar la pantalla. Hay algun motivo especial por el que lo pusiste en una clase distinta?

Comment: Gracias lo primero.Entiendo que tendria que configurar mi propio callback para hacer eso no. La verdad es que queria hacerlo en otra clase por que odio tener casi todo el programa metido en el mainActivity que viene teniendo muchas lineas. 
Al final lo he resuelto de otra manera el boton se encarga de modificar las vistas del activityMain.